# maven project error on tomcat application not starting

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have deployed my maven project tomcat but my web application not starting I am getting following error

```
[ INFO] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[ INFO] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 11 21:55:18 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[ERROR] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.setEnvironment(Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[ INFO] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 11 21:55:18 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[ WARN] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 11 21:55:18 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[ WARN] 2014-04-11 21:55:18 Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Apr 11 21:55:18 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:556)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I can't understand why this error is coming. I have tried removing some jars as well. I am getting this error inside my log file configured through log4j so at least its reaching to my logs configuration.

My pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mavenProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>core</name>
    <description>maven proj</description>

    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- mysql connector -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--google -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.47.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus</id>
            <url>http://repository.codehaus.org/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>myproject.net</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/mavenProject</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my parent pom is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycom</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>mavenProject</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Joda time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>core</module>           
    </modules>
</project>
```

please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three versions of Spring resolved by Maven: one is the one you introduced:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

where the version is 3.1.1.RELEASE, the second is the one already mentioned in another answer and the third is the one introduced by Spring Security dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

and Spring Security 3.1.1.RELEASE depends on Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE.
You can either use a Maven `<exclusion>` to exclude the Spring artifacts from the Spring Security ones or just go with Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE (the one used by Spring Security 3.1.1).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Andrei I changed the version to 3.2 now its working.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent POM loads

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

which has dependencies to Spring 2.0.8. All your other Spring artifacts are 3.1.1.RELEASE...

Remove the `spring-support` dependency.

Comment: In the folder of your `pom.xml` (not parent POM!) run `mvn dependency:tree`. It'll tell you where you load undesired Spring versions.

Comment: @user965884, How did you deploy to tc? created a war and deployed or through a dev. env. like from within eclipse?

Comment: Hi kmansoor, I am creating war using mvn install and then coping the war file inside tomcat/webapp.